# Ajax listener executed twice with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to have two ajax listeners for a p:droppable component.

That works but my listeners are called twice each.

```
<ui:repeat id="orderGroups" value="#{omsOrderActionBean.order.orderGroups}" var="group">
  <p:panel > 
   <p:fieldset id="selectedLineItems" style="margin-top:20px">
    <p:dataTable>
         ...
    </p:dataTable>
   </p:fieldset>
 </p:panel>
 <p:droppable for=":frmItem:tabViewSections:orderGroups:selectedLineItems"
  tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":frmItem:tabViewSections:availableItems" onDrop="handleDrop">
    <p:ajax listener="#{omsOrderActionBean.setSelectedOrderGroup(group)}" immediate="true" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{omsOrderActionBean.onArticleDrop}" update=":frmItem:tabViewSections:outpOrderGroups :frmItem:tabViewSections:availableItems" />
 </p:droppable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Do you know how to avoid that behaviour? Or how to pass an argument to and ajax event?

Answer (score 0):

I highly encourage you not to have two ajax listeners for **the same event**. That increases client/server traffic, performing multiple ajax requests which make your system slow down. Instead, perform only one of them and execute your whole logic there.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{omsOrderActionBean.onDrop}" 
    update=":frmItem:tabViewSections:outpOrderGroups :frmItem:tabViewSections:availableItems" />
```

In order to get the dropped object you should follow the signature specified in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf):

```
public void onDrop(DragDropEvent event) {  
    Group group = (Group) event.getData();  
}
```

Comment: I want both of them to be executed. My problem is that both of them are executed twice. I have 4 executions and not two! How could i do everything in the same event?

Comment: The dropped group comes on the event. Do what you want with it. Then, perform the logic you have inside `onArticleDrop`. After processing it, update what you want. Easy and everything in one call!

Comment: It's not the droped group it's the group in which the item (data) is dropped. I added a bit more information.

Comment: Have a look at [event's API](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/event/DragDropEvent.html). It also allows you to get the id of the component where you drop your object. Just play with that.

Comment: I already tried that but didn't find out how to retrieve the OrderGroup java Object using this id.

Comment: As you implement is actually imposible. You have to retrieve the OrderGroup from the id, so you need to have a `p:droppable` for each of your groups. Then append group's id to the component's id, it'll be useful to retrieve it later. Again, have a look at the showcase, it does something similar, but you are iterating instead.

Comment: I have a p:droppable for each of my groups. My problem is that i have everytime 2 objects which are added in my dataTables, because the event are executed twice. The other solution would be to retrieve my ordergroup using it's id but i don't know how to do that. I also tried to use a <f:setPropertyActionListener but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own problem. I use only one ajax listener. In this listener i get the dropId containing the position of my group. I then simply transform it to an integer and get it from my list of orders:

```
// DropId is of the form: orderGroups:0:selectedLineItems
String[] dropSplit = ddEvent.getDropId().split(":");
// Get the second part to retrieve the correct orderGroup:
int orderGroupPosition = Integer.parseInt(dropSplit[2]);
orderGroups.get(orderGroupPosition);
```